# How align Text in UITextField vertically center?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

Is there some default setting to **center textfield** vertically

Answer (score 7):

Just add the following line of code.

```
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply by using

```
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
```